# Records count exceeded maximum integer value

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Let's say we have a table in SQL Server with primary key of integer type.

What happens if the number of rows in table exceeds maximum value for int data type?

Answer (score 6):

It looks as though your database will refuse to create a new row. Your best bet if you are looking at that barrier is to switch to Bigint, Decimal or using a GUID as the datatype for the primary key:

http://mssqlserver.wordpress.com/2006/12/01/what-happens-when-my-integer-identity-runs-out-of-scope/